# how to convert the CSV to parquet after renaming column name?

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am using the below code to rename one of the column name in a CSV file.

```
input_filepath ='/<path_to_file>/2500.csv'
df_csv =  spark.read.option('header', True).csv(input_filepath)
df1 = df_csv.withColumnRenamed("xyz", "abc")
df1.printSchema()
```

So, the above code works fine. however, I wanted to also convert the CSV to parquet format. If I am correct, the above code will make the changes and put in the memory and not to the actual file. Please correct me if I am wrong.

If the changes are kept in memory, then how can I put the changes to parquet file?
For the file format conversion, I will be using below code snippet

```
df_csv.write.mode('overwrite').parquet()
```

But not able to figure out how to use it in this case. Please suggest

Note:  I am suing Databricks notebook for all the above steps.

Comment: AFAIK, there is a way to convert csv file data to parquet file data by which we can get new parquet file but there no way to convert the file format of the actual file. Only way might be to generate the new parquet file with same name and delete the orginal csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not 100% sure if that will solve your issue but can you try to save your csv like this:

```
df.to_parquet(PATH_WHERE_TO_STORE)
```

Let me know if that helped.

Edit: My workflow usually goes like this

1. Export dataframe as csv
2. Check visually if everything is correct
3. Run this function:

```
import pandas as pd


def convert_csv_to_parquet(path_to_csv):
    df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)
    df.to_parquet(path_to_csv.replace(".csv", ".parq"), index=False)
```

Which goes into the direction of Rakesh Govindulas' comment.